# How does the bottom navigation activity in Android studio work

Tags: java, android, class, bottomnavigationview

I was checking out the bottom navigation activity in android studio and noticed for the classes for each fragment we have the normal fragment class and then the View model class. I had done a bottom navigation activity without a View Model class can you please explain to me what the purpose of this class is?
package com.said.myapplication.ui.dashboard;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.said.myapplication.databinding.FragmentDashboardBinding;

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentDashboardBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textDashboard;
        dashboardViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

The above is just an example code of the DashboardViewModel class.

Comment: It's a template for implementing MVVM pattern which is the actual recommendation for android.